# Reload or retry Android Kotlin Flow after data available in database?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have this flow function to get data from database. But the first time app loaded there is no record in database so I guess Flow is empty. After insert record to DB I need this Flow to reload or something similar to see new data.

```
private var _settingAsync = settingRepository.flowLoadUserSetting(userId).map {
  handleSetting(it)
}.catch { emit(Async.Error(R.string.setting_not_found)) }

val uiState: StateFlow<UiStateB> = combine(_settingAsync, _message, _isLoading) { settingAsync, message, isLoading ->
    when (settingAsync) {
      Async.Loading -> {
        UiStateB(isLoading = true)
      }

      is Async.Error -> {
        UiStateB(message = settingAsync.errorMessage)
      }

      is Async.Success -> {
        UiStateB(
          alarmOn = settingAsync.data!!.alarmOn,
          message = message,
          isLoading = isLoading
        )
      }
    }
  }
.stateIn(
  scope = viewModelScope,
  started = WhileUiSubscribed,
  initialValue = UiStateB(isLoading = true)
)
```

I tried some Flow solutions but it's not work. In another Component I use suspend function it worked well.